# latest nVidia driver but cannot change resolution

Tags: nvidia

New ubuntu-mate 16.04 install and have installed the latest nVidia driver via Software7Updates using this ppa http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu

Under Software & Updates > Other Drivers I see

> Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.26 from nvidia-375 (open
>   source)

But under System > Preferences > Hardware > Displays my monitor is unknown and at a low resolution which can't be changed

A quick google brings me to this page which recommends installing the nVidia driver thru the command line
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-insta...4-xenial-xerus

But I am reluctant, since almost ALL my linux problems have been related to nVidia drivers.

Any driver experts able to offer some help here?

If I run

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA
```

I get

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device
>   [10de:1b00] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])